# Is there a way to use ko.observableArray as map?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Is there a way to use an [ko.observableArray](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) like a map/dictionary?

For example:

```
var arr = ko.observableArray();
arr.push('key', { '.. Some object as value ..' });
```

And then retrive the value using the key:

```
var value = arr['key'];
```

Comment: Have you checked out this guy's dictionary implementation? https://github.com/jamesfoster/knockout.observableDictionary

Comment: @TomHall: Thanks for the link, it looks good.
I've found another more naive implementation:
http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/1563

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found two possible implementations:

1. James Foster / [knockout.observableDictionary](https://github.com/jamesfoster/knockout.observableDictionary) - It has everything a dictionary needs. (Thanks to  Tom Hall for the great find)
2. [A more naive implantation](http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/1563) - suits the basic needs.

I ended up using the observableDictionary, it is fast and simple.

Comment: I forket the "knockout.observableDictionary" and converted it to a Bower package: https://github.com/bennyn/knockout.observableDictionary - So it can be retrieved now as Bower dependency. :)