# Getting an object's value from key in knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

I need to get the value from an object in knockout-generated html. How can I achieve this? My basic code structure is as below.

If there is a better way to achieve the same thing, then I'm all ears.

In my JS code I have:

```
self.myObservable = ko.observable();
self.myObservableArray = ko.observableArray([Obj1, Obj2, Obj3]);
self.someFunction = function () {
  //some ajax calls which gives me an object back with a unique key 
  //so i add this to the observable.
  self.myObservable[uniqueKey] = results;
}
```

In my html I have:

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: myObservableArray">
   <span data-bind="name" id="clickme" data-bind="click: function (){toggle('dynamic-id-of-div')}"></span>
   // This is where i need the value from the oject. The key is the 'name' from the Obj in the foreach
   <div id="dynamic-id-of-div">
       $parent.myObservable[key].name???
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You've tagged *both* 2.0 and 3.0. If your problem is very specific to either, I suggest leaving only that one. Otherwise, I suggest removing both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't really clear (as the other answer stated...), but here's how I understood it (correct me if I'm wrong):

- You want to keep *one* observable object that stores data for certain keys.
- You want to have *one* observable array that stores the keys for which you want to render data.
- A method adds key/value pairs to the first observable dynamically.
- The observable array can receive new keys or remove keys to change what is visible.

Here's an example implementation. I've added some comments to explain what's going on. Let me know if I got your intentions completely wrong...

```js
function VM() {
  var self = this;

  // I've initialized this observable with an empty object so we can add keys later
  self.observableStorage = ko.observable({});
  
  // The data type of the items in this array wasn't clear in your question,
  // I've assumed you meant 'references' to objects (string keys)
  self.observableKeys = ko.observableArray(["key1", "key2", "key3"]);

  self.getData = function() {
    // This is what you would receive from the server
    var mockupServerData = {
      "key1": "Data For Key 1"
    };

    // Use `()` to get the old object out of the observable
    var originalStorage = self.observableStorage();
    
    // This creates a new object that has all the old keys, and adds the new one
    var newStorage = Object.assign({}, originalStorage, mockupServerData);

    // Setting the observable with the new object triggers an UI update
    self.observableStorage(newStorage);
  };
};

var vm = new VM();
ko.applyBindings(vm);

vm.getData();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: observableKeys">
  <li>
    <strong data-bind="text: $data"></strong>:
    <span data-bind="text: $parent.observableStorage()[$data] || 'No Data'"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, really embarrassing but the problem was that I was missing the parenthesis in my HTML. So i was calling $parent.observableStorage[$data] instead of  $parent.observableStorage()[$data]!!!

Thank you for your post though, when i saw your html, i realised it straight away

Answer (score 0):

Remember, unless you're using something like [knockoutjs-es5](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout-es5), you always need to set observables by calling them as a function. You cannot just use plain assignment as with your JS code example, not while also having the view update automatically.

I think you might be looking for an observable dictionary, though your example code is a bit too abastract to tell. In any case, [there is no such thing built in](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12997333/419956) for KnockoutJS. So you either need to use a solution from aforementioned link, or you need to rewrite your application to use a regular observableArray of key value pairs, which would look like this:

```
self.myObservablePseudoDictionary = ko.observableArray([]);
self.myObservableArray = ko.observableArray([Obj1, Obj2, Obj3]);
self.someFunction = function () {
  self.myObservablePseudoDictionary.push({ key: uniqueKey, value: results });
}
```

I cannot help you with accessing this in the view, because your pseudo code doesn't tell me where `key` comes from. There's all sorts of options here, and depending on your context you'll have to pick / create one. That's left as an excercise to the reader :).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div data-bind="foreach: myObservableArray">
   <div data-bind="text: name"></div>
</div>
```

You are inside a foreach so you are now at that objects level. You can also use $data ie:

```
<div data-bind="text: $data.name"></div>
```

But its not necessary.

If your looking to know which object they clicked:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: myObservableArray">
   <div data-bind="click: $parent.setItem.bind($data), text: name, "></div>
</div>
```

add this function to the parent:

```
self.setItem = function (item) {
  // Do what you want with it in here. ie. self.myObservable(item);
  self.myObservable(item);
}
```

If you want to show to the user which one is set:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: myObservableArray">
   <div data-bind="click: $parent.setItem.bind($data), text: name, css: { 'active' : ($parent.myObservable() != null && $parent.myObservable().name() == name())}"></div>
</div>
```

This will add the active class to the selected items div.